# Is it useless to return \Generator if Doctrine's fetchAll() returns array?

Tags: php, doctrine, generator

Aiming to saving memory, when you do a `fetchAll()` over a table with Doctrine's Connection class, it returns an `Array`.

So, if I return a `Generator` in the function that uses the fetchAll, would it be useless as the results are already in memory?

Comment: Yes, it'll be useless. `yeld` work well with line a line (`fetch`, `fread`, `for`/`foreach`/`whield`, etc..).

Comment: If you're just passing the values along unchanged -- yes, it would be useless. If you're manipulating them in some manner to build a new array, it would not be.

Comment: Wow, looking at the source code for Doctrine, there's not a single yield anywhere in either the ORM or the DBAL, that's pretty surprising. I guess backwards compatibility is their main concern.

Comment: @AlexHowansky There're a few interviews from Gulherme Blanco which he says about Doctrine's backward compatibility and about PHP bugs that must exist to Doctrine work as well.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Heh I guess that's why the "Announcing Doctrine 4" article on their main page is an April Fool's Joke.